# jquery to display thumbnail. not working

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010

This jQuery should give me thumbnail view but it does not. Any idea what I am doing wrong? It just gives me the sharepoint icjpg.gif in bigger size.

```
<SCRIPT language=javascript src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type=text/javascript></SCRIPT> 

<SCRIPT defer type=text/javascript> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("img[src$='icjpg.gif']").each(SetImage); 

}); 
function SetImage() 
{ 

$(this).attr('height','100'); 
$(this).attr('src',$(this).parent().attr('href')); 

} 
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code works. You have to put in the relative url to the library

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("img[src$='icjpg.gif']").each(SetImage);

});
function SetImage()
{
    $(this).attr('height','100');
    $(this).attr('src','/managedpath/sitename/library/'+$(this).attr('title'));
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type=text/javascript> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("img[src*=icjpg.gif]").each(SetImage); 

}); 
function SetImage() 
{ 

$(this).css({'height':'100px', "width":"auto"}); 
$(this).attr('src',$(this).parent().attr('href')); 

} 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the post but still not working. Anything else I need to do?

Comment: `$(this).attr('src',$(this).parent().attr('href')); ` wat is this line doing?

Comment: I can take it out. Not sure why is there. The idea is to display pictures in the document library in thumbnail style. Shouldn't the code replace icjpg.gif to whatever the picture name in the library?

Comment: Can you please post the html?

Comment: I don't have the html. I added a content editor web part to the all documents view by edit page and referenced jquery JS file.

Comment: I tried this $(this).parent().attr('href',$(this).attr('src')); but it still does not give me thumbnail view. by the way the original article can be found at http://sharepointblog.kellerschroeder.com/2009/05/using-jquery-to-display-image.html

Comment: any other ideas. I spent about 3 to 4 hours and still stuck. I would appreciate it.